# Best way to deal with a FileNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, exception

so I'm on a project which requires me to read data from a .txt file. In order to do that I used the with function and now I want to deal with an eventual FileNotFoundError in case the file isn't named correctly or isn't there at all

```
while True:
    try:
        with open("etalons.txt", "r") as fichier: 
            etalons = []
            for ligne in fichier:
               temp = ligne.split(',')
               ets = {
                       'conc' : temp[0],
                       'abs' :  temp[1]
                       }
               etalons.append(ets) # stockage des dicos dans liste
        break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found. Check if the file is in the folder and it's name. ")
        time.sleep(20)
```

I came up with this but I feel like there is a best way to do this (seems overprocessed or something). Would something without the while loop be more appropriate or do you see another way to do this in a cleaner way ?

I'm new to python so I will take any piece of advice

Comment: Why the ``while`` loop? Will ``etalons.txt`` eventually be created if it doesn't exist yet? Otherwise, consider to abort the process once it's clear that your assumptions (``etalons.txt`` exists) don't hold.

Comment: I didn't want to abort and let time to the user to correct the file name but it's probably better to just abort. I got rid of the while loop and just put a sys.exit() in the except block. Thanks you very much